# Rearrange Dialogue Documents to Dataframe

Tags: python, corpus

I plan to analyze some conference documents, and before the analysis, I need to rearrange these documents into data frame. The format I expect is that for each row of the data, the first value is the speaker and the second value is the utterance of that speaker. For instance, ["Jo", "I just had tacos."]. The sample document can be reached [here](http://tpliu.xyz/%20201087.txt). Below is the progress so far:

```
file = open('the document','r') 
Name = []
sentence = []

for line in file:
    if line.find("Column") != -1:
        continue
    if line.find("Section") or line.find("Index") or line.find("Home Page"):
        continue
    if line.find(':') != -1:
        tokens = line.split(":")
        Name.append(tokens[0])
    else:
        sentence.append(line + " ")
```

My first question is that how I can combine the speaker and the utterance in one list and then search for the next person. The second question is that is there any better way to get rid of the content before `Oral Answers to Questions` and after `The House divided: Ayes 240, Noes 329.Division No. 54][9.59 pm`.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have come up with a simple solution. This simple solution has three parts

- When there is an empty line
- When the line ends with `:`
- Otherwise

Here is the code:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict


def clean_speaker(sp):
    sp = re.sub(r"(\(\w+\))", "", sp) #remove single words within parentheses
    sp = re.sub(r"(\d+\.?)", "", sp) #remove digits such as 1. or 2.
    return sp.strip()



document = []
with open('the document','r') as fin:
    foundSpeaker = False
    dialogue = defaultdict(str)
    for line in fin.readlines():
        line = line.strip() #remove white-spaces
        #----- when line is empty -----
        if not line:
            dialogue = defaultdict(str)
            foundSpeaker = False
        #----- When line ends with : -----
        elif line[-1] == ":":
            if dialogue:
                document.append(dialogue)
                dialogue = defaultdict(str)
            foundSpeaker = True
            dialogue["Speaker"] = clean_speaker(line[:-1])
        #----- Otherwise -----
        else:
            if foundSpeaker:
                dialogue["Sentence"] += " " + line
            else:
                if dialogue:
                    document.append(dialogue)
                    dialogue = defaultdict(str)
                    foundSpeaker = False
                continue
```

Now, the variable `document` has all the dialogue in the given file... it's a list of dictionary where each dictionary has just two keys (`speaker`, and `sentence`). So, we can see what's inside `document` like so:

```
for d in document:
    for key, value in d.items():
        print(key+":", value)
```

Or you can do something smarter where you convert that list into `pandas.dataframe` and write that dataframe into csv like so:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(document).to_csv('document.csv')
```

Now, open `document.csv` and you will find everything in order... I hope this helps you